# Achieve blur in the foreground and the background with a Nikon Coolpix 530

Tags: nikon, focus

I have been trying to take photographs of items in the mid-ground and am not getting sufficient blur on my foregrounds and backgrounds. I have tried using different distances between my subjects, adjusting my f-stops and I am only getting a slight blur effect at best.

Comment: Related: [How to focus on an area correctly, while still blurring everything else?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87862/how-to-focus-on-an-area-correctly-while-still-blurring-everything-else)

Comment: Viewing size matters, too. You'll see less blur on your camera's rear LCD screen where everything is scaled down than you will on a larger display. [Why do viewing conditions affect Depth of Field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85606/why-do-viewing-conditions-affect-depth-of-field)

Answer (score 0):

You have three options (as far as I know) to make background and/or foreground more out of focus:

1. Use bigger sensor, open aperture. Big sensor and wide open aperture will help you to create very shallow DoF. In your case the sensor is very
   small, you can't change the lens. So this is not applicable
2. Increase the ratio of the distance between the object and
   background. Get as close as possible to the object and as far as
   possible to the background. This is not always possible but you can
   play in this direction
3. Use longest possible focal length. This can help you to minimize the
   depth of field (area which is in focus)

You can play "offline" and check DoF on [this](http://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html) website (no affiliation with the author of the site)

P.S. I just realize there is fourth way to do what you want. You can accomplish the desired effect in post-production. Almost any editor will permit you to add blur to selected areas of your image.