# What variables define DoF?

Tags: depth-of-field

I want to be able to see a frame and 'calculate' (either mathematically or intuitively) the DoF of the picture to be taken.

The most basic variable would be the aperture; my question is do other variables also have effect on DoF? Especially the distance from sensor to object.

Suppose I want to photograph an object with dimensions X and my camera with aperture set on f/1.4 only focuses on *half* of the object. Can I change something *other* than the aperture to ensure the whole object is in focus?

Comment: The lists in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/87870/15871) enumerate the major variables. The overall question is also related to how only part of a subject is in focus. [How to focus on an area correctly, while still blurring everything else?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87862/15871)

Answer (score 0):

There are three main factor that determine the DOF:

- Distance to the subject
- Focal length
- Aperture

There are useful [online calculators](http://www.dofmaster.com/dofjs.html) to calculate the required distance to have the subject(s) within the DoF.

Regarding equations to calculate the Hyperfocal distance, near distance of acceptable sharpness, you can use the following formulas:

**Hyperfocal**

[image]

**Near distance of acceptable sharpness**

[image]

**Far distance of acceptable sharpness**

[image]

where:

- H is the hyperfocal distance, mm
- f is the lens focal length, mm
- s is the focus distance
- Dn is the near distance for acceptable sharpness
- Df is the far distance for acceptable sharpness
- N is the f-number
- c is the circle of confusion, mm

[Source](http://www.dofmaster.com/equations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically i don't know these equations but the other way you can change you DoF is by changing your focal Length, using a prime lens and increasing and decreasing of the subject from the film plane.